# Разные значения функции в разных компиляторах

Tags: c++, c, алгоритм, математика, ряды

Есть программа, которая вычисляет значение функции на отрезке [-1; 1] поделенном на n равных(подается в stdin) ln(2+x) и значение этой же функции по ряду Тейлора: `ln2 + x/2 - x^2/2^3 +...+(-1)^(n-1) * (x^n/(n*2^n)))`.
Очень странное поведение, компилирую в Clion при n = 10 выводит-

```
5| -0.000000   0.693147 40378677826926566000000000000...
```

компилирую в Ubuntu терминале при n = 10 выводит- 5| -0.000000   0.693147   0.000000

Затем компилирую в Clion при n = 100 выводит-

```
50| 0.000000   0.693147   0.693147
```

(это правильный ответ, так как значения совпадают)

НО! компилирую в Ubuntu и выводит -

```
50| 0.000000   0.693147   0.000000
```

Помогите понять, в чем проблема такого отличия? И как сделать чтобы при нулевом значении x выводило правильный ответ(при всех остальных значениях вывод в ubuntu и clion совпадает)

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

double macheps()
{

    double e = 1.0;

    while (1.0 + e / 2.0 > 1.0)
        e /= 2.0;
    return e;

}


struct Point
{

    double x;
    double y;

};


int oddEven(unsigned p)
{

    return (p % 2 == 0) ? 1 : -1;

}


double f(unsigned p, double x)
{

    double y = log(2);
    for (unsigned i = 0; i <= p; ++i) {

            y += (oddEven(i) * pow(x, i + 1)) / ((i + 1) * pow(2, i + 1));

    }
    return y;

}

double g(double x)
{

    return log(2 + x);

}


void TaylorCalculation(unsigned iterationCount, double a, double b, double (*taylor_f)(unsigned, double), double (*real_f)(double))
{

    double step = ( b - a ) / iterationCount;
    struct Point* points = (struct Point*)malloc(sizeof(struct Point) * iterationCount);
    double eps = macheps();
    double x = a;

    for(unsigned i = 0; i < iterationCount; ++i, x+=step) {
        unsigned p = 0;
        while(fabs(real_f(x) - taylor_f(p, x)) > eps * 100)
        {

            points[i].x = x;
            points[i].y = taylor_f(p, x);
            ++p;
            if(p >= 100) {

                break;

            }
        }
        printf("%d| %lf %10lf %10lf\n", i, x, real_f(x), points[i].y);

    }
}

int main()
{

    unsigned n;
    double a = -1, b = 1;
    scanf("%u", &n);
    TaylorCalculation(n, a, b, f, g);

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*"Да понять-то его, надежа-царь, немудрено..." (с)*

Смотрим комментарии, помня, что x==0, и вначале p == 0.

```
double f(unsigned p, double x)
{
    double y = log(2);
    // Этот цикл выполняется 1 раз, и ничего не прибавляет к y
    // для указанных x и p равных 0
    for (unsigned i = 0; i <= p; ++i) {
            y += (oddEven(i) * pow(x, i + 1)) / ((i + 1) * pow(2, i + 1));
    }
    return y;  // возвращает log(2)
}
```

Итак, и `real_f(0)`, и `taylor_f(p, 0)` сразу возвращают одинаковое значение - `log(2)`.

```
    unsigned p = 0;

    // Это условие НЕ выполняется сразу же, так что тело цикла НЕ выполняется
    while(fabs(real_f(x) - taylor_f(p, x)) > eps * 100)
    {

        points[i].x = x;
        // А значит, и этого присваивания не происходит
        points[i].y = taylor_f(p, x);
        ++p;
        if(p >= 100) {

            break;

        }
    }
    // И когда дело доходит до вывода, выводится неприсвоенное значение.

    // И самое интересное - НЕИНИЦИАЛИЗИРОВАННОЕ!! 
    // Т.е. где-то - 0, где-то - какой-то странный мусор...

    printf("%d| %lf %10lf %10lf\n", i, x, real_f(x), points[i].y);
```

Все понятно?